# If $\log_{0.5}\sin x=1-\log_{0.5}\cos x$ , then the number of solutions in the interval [$-2\pi, 2\pi$] is?

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

In the given [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAYrY.jpg),the answer gives only two solutions. However, when a graph of sin 2x is plotted, we see that it attains a value of 1 at four points in the given interval. What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: i get $$-\frac{7}{4}\pi,-\frac{3}{4}\pi,\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{5}{4}\pi$$

Comment: So do I. I wanted to know whether I was making an error.

Comment: You have no error in your calculations.

Comment: So is the given solution incorrect?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: If we assume to work in $\mathbb R$, $\log(\cdot)$  is defined only when the argument is greater than $0$, which means that both sine and cosine must be postive, in this equation. A valid solution must be in the first quadrant. Correct?

Comment: I think so,is that in your text book? Then write the author a mail.

Comment: This is true, check the solutions again!

Comment: @Matteo: You may be right. But still, the given answer does not satisfy that condition either.

Comment: "The answer says b)"???  what does b) mean?  Do you expect us to be mind readers?  You *do* realize we don't actually have you question or assignment in front of us, don't you?

Comment: @fleablood is right. How about you re-write entire question and answer in the body of the post?

Comment: and, yes, the book **is** wrong since $-\frac{3\pi}{4}$ would give negative arguments for the logarithms. See below.

Answer (score 1):

The book is giving one solution $[-2\pi,2\pi]$ but giving another $(0, \pi/2)$.  It looks like the book is inconsistent, but you are correct in your answer.

The general solution for the equation above is $$\dfrac {\pi}{4} + 2 \pi k, k \in (0, 1)$$.

EDIT: Removed the $\pm$ from the previous solution as this would result in negative logarithms; expanded the domain.

Comment: in the second quadrant $\cos x$ is negative so the equation has no meaning.

Comment: Duly noted.  I've corrected my post above and removed the $\pm$ from the original solution.

Comment: the general solution is actually $\frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi$, with $k \in \Bbb Z$, in order to always end up in the first quadrant. Then, if solutions in $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$ are required, those are $$-\frac{7}{4}\pi, \ \frac{1}{4}\pi$$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that in $\Bbb R$ the property $\log \alpha + \log\beta = \log\alpha\beta$, is only valid when *both* $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are strictly positive.
The equation
$$\log_{0.5}\sin x=1-\log_{0.5}\cos x$$
is thus equivalent to
$$
\begin{cases}
\sin x> 0\\
\cos x > 0\\
\log_{0.5}\sin x\cos x = 1,
\end{cases}
$$
meaning
$$
\begin{cases}
2k\pi < x < \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\\
\sin x \cos x = \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}\ ,\ k\in \Bbb Z
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\begin{cases}
2k\pi < x < \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\\
\sin 2x  = 1.
\end{cases}
$$
Solving with respect to $x$ the second equation yields
$$
\begin{cases}
2k\pi < x < \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\\
x = \frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi
\end{cases}
$$
The required solutions in $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$ therefore are $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $x = \frac{\pi}{4}-2\pi$.